# Creating artificially parsed arguments

Tags: python

My program "program.py" has the form:

```
if __name__=='__main__':
     args = parse_args()
     main_function(args)
```

However, if I import program.py as a module and run program.main_function, how can I pass the parsed arguments structure as an argument to the main_function?

Here is the definition of the parse_args()

```
 def parse_args():
     parser=argparse.ArgumentParser()
     parser.add_argument(...)
     args=parser.parse_args()
     return args
```

Comment: what does `parse_args()` return? If you are using the argparse method of that name it's just a lis of string.

Answer (score 0):

If we are talking about [argparse.parse_args](http://file:///usr/share/doc/python3-docs/html/library/argparse.html#option-value-syntax) from the standard library, just pass the list of arguments explicitly.

For example, if you call your program from the command line with these arguments:

```
program --verbose --mode=3 file1 file2
```

the shell splits the command line into five words, the program name and its four arguments. These are stored in [sys.argv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.argv).

To achieve the same effect directly from Python:

```
 args = parse_args(['--verbose', '--mode=3', 'file1' , 'file2'])
 main_function(args)
```

UPDATE - parse_args modification:

```
 def parse_args(arglist=None):
     parser=argparse.ArgumentParser()
     parser.add_argument(...)
     args=parser.parse_args(arglist)
     return args
```

Comment: How do I connect it though with `argparse.ArgumentParser()`?